# Calling Realm.asyncOpen always fails with "Operation Cancelled"

Tags: ios, swift, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I'm trying to asynchronously open a `Realm`, but it keeps failing with the error:

`Error Domain=io.realm.sync Code=4 "Operation canceled" UserInfo=
{NSLocalizedDescription=Operation canceled, statusCode=89}`

I'm not sure why this happens, especially because it worked before (as in a few days ago).

My code looks like:

```
let realmURL = URL(string: "realm://\(aValidIP):\(aValidPort)/~/someRealm")
let config = Realm.Configuration(syncConfiguration: SyncConfiguration(user: aLoggedInUser,
                                                                              realmURL: realmURL))
Realm.asyncOpen(configuration: config,
                        callbackQueue: DispatchQueue.main) { (realm, error) in
                            if let error = error {
                                print(error) // <-- This error holds the one explained above
                                return
                            }
                            self.realm = realm
        }
```

Does someone know *why* the operation cancels? What are reasons for `asyncOpen` to fail?

Comment: Is the `realm` returned in the callback `nil`?

Comment: Can you file an issue against Realm's bug tracker on GitHub at https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues and enclose a sample project so we can investigate?

Comment: @CliftonLabrum yeah the returned realm is `nil`, do you know what's going wrong?
I'll file an issue as well.

Comment: @Gee.E Are you able to connect with the same URL and user using the Realm Browser?

Comment: I can't...but by now I'm noticing that the realm I'm trying to open has `no access` when I'm checking it at the object server. Even though the same user made the realm. I'm checking that issue now too (sorry for the late reply, was on a vacation).